# Applying FFTW for gray scale image

Tags: c++, fftw

I have a grey scale image. I want to implement fftw on it. So, so far what i did is,

```
int g;
int width = pixmap.width();
int height = pixmap.height();

const int Lx = width;
const int Lt = height;
int var_x;
int var_t;

double F[Lx][Lt][16];
fftw_complex *in, *out, *result;
fftw_plan p;

in = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*Lx*Lt);
out = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*Lx*Lt);
result = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) *Lx *Lt);
p = fftw_plan_dft_2d(Lx, Lt, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_MEASURE);

ifstream input;
input.open("2D_function");
for (int x = 0;x < Lx;x++)
{
    for (int t = 0; t < Lt; t++)
   {
       input >> var_t;
       input >> var_x;
       input >> F[x][t][0];

   }
}

for (int x = 0; x < Lx; x++)
{
   for (int t = 0; t < Lt; t++)
   {
       in[t + Lt*x][0] = F[x][t][0];
   }
}
input.close();

fftw_execute(p);

for (int x = 0; x < Lx; x++)
{
   for (int t = 0; t < Lt; t++)
   {
       F[x][t][0] = out[t + Lt*x][0];
       F[x][t][1] = out[t + Lt*x][1];
   }
}
for (int x = 0; x < Lx; x++)
{
   for (int t = 0; t < Lt; t++)
   {
       std::cout<<F[x][t][0]<<F[x][t][1]<<std::endl;

           }
       }
```

so now i have an fft transform depending on the width and height of an image. But my understanding is that this the width and height here would just be numbers and will not have the pixel values so the FFT transform generated is some random output. How do i generate the FFT transform so that it takes the image as input

Comment: when i use 'FFTW_execute(P)' how do i know if it executing thing on the image or on a random set of values?

Comment: i tried using that already and it was executing it, but i donot understand if it executing it on the image or on some random values.

Comment: You need to zero all the imaginary parts of your input data.